# Mutate useSWR data (local state) without revalidating?

Tags: reactjs, http, next.js, swr

I have some data from a public API that I fetched using useSWR, now I want to operate on that. Previously, I would `setState` with the response from an API and then when operating on it I would just overwrite it with `setState`.

In my case, I want to sort the data with a button press. it looks like this

```
function Component() {
   const { data } = useSWR(...)

  function sortData() {
    data.sort(...)
  }
}
```

How can I modify `data` like this without having useSWR revalidate and fetch new data? This is strictly a client-side need, the API does not need to worry about this sorting.

Thanks!

Comment: Simply calling `data.sort()` would not have `useSWR` revalidate and refetch the data. What's causing it? Can you provide a [mre]?

Answer (score 1):

Using [swr v2.0.4](https://swr.vercel.app/), the signature to achieve this is `mutate(key, callback, options)`

See the docs: https://swr.vercel.app/docs/mutation.en-US#parameters

1. `callback`: similar to react's `useState` hook `setState` callback i.e `(prevData) => newData`
2. `options`: `options.revalidate` to `false` skips revalidating or fetching data (in the example below).

```js
import { mutate } from 'swr';

function Component() {
   const { data } = useSWR('key', ...)

  function sortData() {
    mutate('key',
      (prevData) => {
        const sortedData = [...prevData].sort();
        return sortedData
      },
      { revalidate: false } // prevents revalidating the cache
    )

  }
}
```

I believe you can also use `mutate` directly from `useSWR` return (but I am unsure of the API). Probably

```js
  const { data, mutate } = useSWR(...)
  mutate(
    (prevData) => {
      const sortedData = [...prevData].sort();
      return sortedData
    },
    { revalidate: false } // prevents revalidating the cache
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say because you're not saying what causes SWR to revalidate but here are the main solutions I know of :

- move the hook to the parent component if you want to avoid the re-fetch caused by the sort but you still want to fetch normally otherwise ;
- pass null / a function as cache key : https://swr.vercel.app/docs/conditional-fetching if you want to only fetch in certain controlled conditions ;
- use useSWRImmutable : https://swr.vercel.app/docs/revalidation if you don't want to re-fetch at all.